# Jmeter assert return results are not empty or empty

Tags: json, jmeter, assertions, jmeter-plugins

I am new to JMeter. I have an AJAX app. At some point there is a query that checking the data based on the distance criteria. If the distance is too short, the return is no results in the following JSON format: `[]`. If the distance range is big enough, the data is populated and returned as JSON Array.

I am trying to put the assertion to know when there is results or when there is no results, i.e. `[]`. How to do this?

I tried JSON Path `$[0]` and Value `[]`. I also tried Expected `null`. These doesn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated. I feel I will need to write the shell script, but feel it can be complicated.

Also our app is a bit not standard from what I saw. JSON doesn't start with `{[]}`, it starts with `[{}]`.

Comment: `{[]}` is not a valid JSON, `[{}]` is. Also can you please post a fragment of the test plan you are trying to fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing for an empty match is fairly simple, all you need is:

- Use a wildcard expression: `$.*` as JSON Path
- Paste **exact** empty response into "Expected Value", any extra space or empty string will cause assertion failure.

[image: JSON Path Assertion]

See:

- [JSONPath - XPath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) - for JSON Path language overview and syntax
- [Advanced Usage of the JSON Path Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter) - for dealing with non-standard query types i.e. conditional select, working with arrays and getting multiple matches with a single query

Comment: Dmitri, as always your answer is on target. Thanks a lot.